# App-Auth Android Example Error in AuthState constructor

Tags: android, appauth

I am using the example for AppAuth-Android from [this github repository](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)

The gradle configuration I am using is

```
compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.5.1'
```

The error thrown is for the lines below:

```java
AuthorizationServiceConfiguration config = new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
        mConfiguration.getAuthEndpointUri(),
        mConfiguration.getTokenEndpointUri(),
        mConfiguration.getRegistrationEndpointUri());

mAuthStateManager.replace(new AuthState(config));
```

The error states that `AuthState(AuthorizationServiceConfiguration)` constructor not defined.

Is the example not updated for the library version or is there any other error.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead maintainer of AppAuth here - I believe I added that method after the release of 0.5.1, you'll need to wait for the 0.6.0 release to use it.

Comment: Could you point me to an example that would be compatible with 0.5.1

Comment: In 0.5.1, you can construct an AuthState with no parameter: `new AuthState()`.